# How Do I Back Up Photos From Multiple Computers Avoiding Duplicates?

Tags: google-photos

I have several directories on several computers that contain photos that I have copied from my phones SD cards over the years.

I know for a fact that there are duplicates among them by using various tools.

However, I don't know if I have already backed up these photos to Google Photos.

The newer ones are almost certainly on Google Photos but the older ones are less likely to be there since at some point I didn't have Google Photos on my phone.

Can I just mass upload every photo from every directory on each PC and assume that Google Photos will avoid uploading duplicates?

The goals I want to achieve are:

- Make sure I have backups of these photos somewhere
- Delete the photos from the hard disks of the old PCs
- Avoid wasting cloud storage with duplicates
- Avoid having to manually go through and delete thousands of duplicates that might get created

What is my best approach for this in 2020?